# registering and resetting the convolution output in verilog

Tags: verilog, reset, convolution, cpu-registers

so I have a module that  does convolution, it takes a data input and the filter input , where input is array of 9 numbers , every posedge of the clk  these two inputs are being multiplied and then added accumulatively, i.e I save every  new multiplication product into a register. after each 9 iterations I have to save the result and reset it , but I have to do it in one clock cycle, since my new data is coming on the next posedge. So the issue that I am facing is how to not save data and reset the out without losing data? Please help if you have any suggestions. It also need to be mentioned that my conv_module is a sub-module and I will be instantiating it in a top module , so I have to access all the inputs and outputs from uptop.

This is the code that I've written so far, but it does not work the way I want it, cause I cannot tap the array of output numbers from the top module.

```
module mult_conv( input clk,
              input rst,
                     input signed [4:0] a,
                     input signed[2:0] b,
                     output reg signed[7:0] out
                         );

wire signed [7:0] mult;
reg signed [7:0] sum;

reg [3:0] counter;
reg do_write;
reg [7:0] out_top;

assign mult = {{3{a[4]}},a} * {{5{b[2]}},b};


always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin
   if (rst)
   begin
      counter  <= 4'h0;
      addr     <= 'h0;
      sum      <= 0;
      do_write <= 1'b0;
   end // rst
   else
   begin
      if (counter == 4'h8)
      begin // we have gathered 9 samples
         counter <= 4'h0;
         // start again so ignore old sum
         sum <= mult;
            out <= sum;
            out_top <= out;
      end
      else
      begin
         counter <= counter  + 4'h1;
         // Add results
         sum <= sum + mult;
            out <= 0;
            out_top <= out_top;
      end
      // Write signal has to be set one cycle early
      do_write = (counter==4'h7);
   end // clocked
end // always


        endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a plethora of errors in that code.
Apart from that you have a 3Mega bit memory from which you use only 1 in 9 locations.

1. You write `out` in two places. That does not work.
2. You use a %9. That can not be mapped onto hardware.
3. You have a sel signal which somehow controls your sum.

On top of that I understand you want to bring the whole memory out.

Your code because it needs to be drastically re-written. 
But your biggest problem is that you definitely can't make the memory come out. What ever post-processing you want to do you have two choices:

1. Process the output data as it appears.
2. Store the data outside the module in a memory and have another process read that memory.

I think only (1) is the correct way because your signal can have infinite length.

As to fixing this code a bit:

- Replace the %9 with a counter to count from 0 to 8.
- Process out in in clocked section. See below
- Move the addr and sel generating logic in here. Keep it all together.

Below is the basic code of how to do a 9-sequence convolution. I have to ignore 'sel' as I have no idea of the timing. I have also added address generation and a write signal so the result can be store in an external memory. But I still think you should process the result on the fly.

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge rts)
begin
   if (rst)
   begin
      counter  <= 4'h0;
      addr     <= 'h0;
      sum      <= 0;
      do_write <= 1'b0;
   end // rst
   else
   begin
      if (counter == 4'h8)
      begin // we have gathered 9 samples
         counter <= 4'h0;
         addr <= addr  + 1;
         // start again so ignore old sum
         sum <= mult;
      end
      else
      begin
         counter <= counter  + 4'h1;
         // Add results
         sum <= sum + mult;             
      end

      // Write signal has to be set one cycle early
      do_write = (counter==4'h7);
   end // clocked
end // always
```

*(Code above was entered on-the fly, may contain syntax, typing or other errors!!)*

As you can see the trick is to know when to add the old result or when to ignore the old sum and start again.

<sub>(I spend about 3/4 of an hour on that so on my normal tariff you would have to pay me $93.75 :-)</sub>

---

I provided the basic code to let you work out the specifics. I did nothing with out but left that to you.
do_write and addr where for a possible memory to pick up the result. Without memory you can drop addr but do_write should tell you when a new convolution result is available, in which case you might want to give a it a different name. e.g. 'sum_valid'.

Comment: Hi @Oldfart, thanks for helping me again and giving suggestions of code fixing ) . However, I have couple questions: 1.So I went through your code several times and I could not see the line where you assign out to sum and where out is being reset to 0. Another thing is that I don't undestand the use of  do_write signal in here. In my code the output need to be registered in out every 9 cycles, and then on the top module I will assign this value to another reg , for ex. out_top <= out. So far I could not manage it, cause every time out_top becomes to be 0.

Comment: I edited my code in my question , where I used part of what you provided and added the logic that I need to implement. I wrote the tb and tested the simulation, nevertheless the value of out_top is always assigned to 0, since it refers to the value of out after 9th cycle.. I still could not figured how to fix that

Comment: I agree that the first solution that you proposed "Process the output data as it appears" is most appropriate  for me and I guess at this point I don't to use address then. Btw, select signal was there to control of what is being added into sum, since at the first iteration the sum  was x, that's why I needed to store 0 in there. Idk why I didn't think of assigning directly "0"  to sum  in "rst" state like you did it, so thank you for that as well.